# Distribution of maximizer for asymmetric random walk with non-integer step size

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Consider the random walk $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ with step size 
\begin{equation}
    X_i =
    \left\{
        \begin{array}{}
                a & \mathrm{with\ probability\ } p \\
                b & \mathrm{with\ probability\ } 1-p \\
        \end{array} 
    \right.
\end{equation}
where $a$ and $b$ are numbers which are not integer multiples of each other, or even irrational numbers.

Further assume that $\mathbb{E}X<0$ and $S_0=0$, how can I get the distribution of the maximizer of this random walk? Or to simplify the problem a little bit, what it the probability that the maximizer is at $S_0$?

Edit: Here's a simpler question, is the distribution a scale family? If so, what would be the scale parameter? I think $\mathbb{E}X/\sqrt{Var(X)}$ makes some sense but I was not quite sure, any thoughts on this?

Comment: I saw many results on integer valued $a$ and $b$, but couldn't find anything on non integer $a$ and $b$